# Is using Linq to SQL in a MembershipProvider implementation safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm creating a custom `MembershipProvider` for an ASP.NET MVC website, and I was planning on using `LINQ to SQL` for the internals, as I am for the rest of the website.  Are there any issues with this, specifically any security issues it causes?

Comment: `I'm creating a custom MembershipProvider` - I guess the answer will depend on how you create it. This is to say that answering your question is kind of difficult without more details.

Comment: @Darin I'm going to be hashing the password in a table with a salt and all that, I just wondered if there should be any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq-To-SQL prevents SQL injection attacks; so any potential holes would normally be the result of logical errors created in the customer membership provider.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your implementation there should be no more of a security risk than writing the calls in TSQL or stored procedures.